# Where should the apostrophe go in "Cas's Cookies"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

My name is Cas and I make cookies to sell. I call my little enterprise Cas's Cookies. Is this the proper use of an apostrophe?

If I put the apostrophe after the second s then it changes my name to Cass (which I am not)

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6295/when-a-word-ends-in-s-or-x-do-you-add-s-or-just-an?rq=1

Comment: You might want to change the name for purposes of branding. Or exaggerate it. You could use a HUGE or FAT apostrophe. I can't show you here. You could also do:  Cookies by Cas

Comment: I would avoid an apostrophe in a business name. (Cas/Cas's/Cass/Cass's gets confusing fast.) Presuming that your business is in an English speaking country, people might confuse Cass (a common name in English), Kas (which is also common) and Cas (which is not). As @Lambie wrote, "Cookies by Cas" or such, avoiding the apostrophe, seems like a good idea.

Comment: Also how do you pronounce it. "cas" or "kaz" or ???

Answer (score 1):

> Cas's Cookies

You are correct!

If your name were Cass, then your enterprise would be Cass's Cookies. If you see `s'` at the end of a word, then generally the `s` is from the plural. For example two cousins who make and sell cookies could call their enterprise "Cousins' Cookies".

Comment: That is absolutely right, but there are lots of people who would say he is absolutely wrong.  If you stand on Westminster Bridge, just  by Big Ben, in London and look to your east you will see the ancient hospital, known to all Londoners as "Saint Thomas's Hospital". You will then read in large letters across the top of the building "St Thomas' Hospital". Call your business "Cas's Cookies" if you like. Maybe the people who think that is wrong will have their attention drawn to it.

Comment: @JeremyC That's a good point. Is that maybe historical? Are there examples of `Thomas'` from recent years?