# How to pronounce "Stannis's"?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives

I know that the "s" becomes "z" when it comes after a voiced sound. And it is pronounced as "s" when it comes after a voiceless sound. I also know rules about possessives but I don't know how natives pronounce a word when it ends in **S** and "apostrophe S" is added to it.

For example: "**Stannis's** army".

Do you add another syllable to it? Like **Stannisiz**? or just **Stannis** and ignore the possessive S?

I really have difficulty in pronouncing words that end in S and possessive S is attached to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When a word ends in 's' or 'x', do you add 's or just an '?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6295/when-a-word-ends-in-s-or-x-do-you-add-s-or-just-an) Specifically, [*there is a rule saying that if somebody's name ends in 's', you can use **either** Charles' or Charles's and **pronounce** those forms **accordingly**.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/6298/126) So if you have a problem enunciating that second **/s/**, just don't bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an extra syllable is added to its pronunciation, so it's pronounced *Stannisiz* ([stænəsɪz]*).

Whenever a word ends in a [sibilant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant) or an [affricate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affricate_consonant) and you add the **'s** to it, the **'s** is pronounced [ɪz]. The pronunciation without the extra syllable is also common.

- **Sibilants:**  /s, z, ʃ, ʒ/
- **Affricates:** /t͡ʃ, d͡ʒ/

I have explained why add an extra syllable for the **'s** in [another answer to a question asking *Why are there three pronunciations for the plural “-s”?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/268682/106592), I'll just copy-paste the relevant bit:

### Sibilants + S

- #### [ʃ] or [ʒ] + S

When a word ends in a sibilant [ʃ], it's voiceless and when we add the [s] then we get *[ʃs] cluster, which isn't permissible, so we insert a vowel between both the sibilants in order to break that cluster and conform with the rules. After inserting the vowel, we get [ʃɪs], now we already said that the *-s* is [z] after a voiced sound, and the vowel is voiced, so we change the [s] back to a [z] and get [ɪz] therefore the word *bushes* is pronounced *bush[ɪz]*. When a word ends in [ʒ], we do the same as above.

- #### [s] or [z] + S

[s] and [z]  are sibilants, but I'm going to explain them separately. When a word ends in a **[s]**, it's a voiceless sound, so we add the [s] form of the *-s* ending; bus + [s] → *[bʌ**ss**], here we have a [geminated](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/268352/106592) s and as we read in the rules that tautosyllabic geminates aren't allowed, therefore we insert an epenthetic vowel [ɪ ~ ə] to break the geminate: [bʌsɪs], we change the terminal [s] back to a [z] because the sound preceding is a voiced (vowels are always voiced): [ˈbʌsɪz].

The same goes for words that end with a **[z]**: when a word ends in a [z], it's voiced so we add the [z] form of the *-s* ending: rose + [z] → *[ɹəʊ**zz**], here we have a geminated z, so we need to break it, therefore we insert a vowel: [ˈɹəʊzɪz]

- #### Affricates + S

Affricates—[t͡ʃ] and [d͡ʒ]—are complex segments. The second segment in both the affricates is a sibilant. So we get Sibilant + Sibilant, which isn't allowed. Therefore we insert a vowel between the affricate and the [s] or [z] to break that cluster. Beach + [s] → *[biːt͡ʃs] + [ɪ ~ ə] → [biːt͡ʃɪs]

It holds true for possessives and present singular -s too.

Comment: You will sometimes hear people say something more like *Stannis army*, but yeah it's supposed to be the extra syllable. Also when you're speaking quickly, the vowel can become a schwa or disappear entirely, and the *z* can just become a *s*, so you get a quick *ss-ss* sound. That's the key part really, adding a *z/s* sound to the end of a word to make it possessive - if the word already ends in that sound, you need a distinct extra one so you can hear the difference. Just in case that makes the pronunciation a bit easier!

Comment: Ill-formed constructs are marked with a preceding asterisk.