# What's the difference in pronunciation between case-sensitive and k-sensitive?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english

This question is probably simple, but the rule behind it may apply generally.

My assumption is:

> If the end of a word duplicate the beginning of the next word, the beginning of the next word should be stressed. Pronounce with no stress otherwise.

Sorry for that I am not familiar with academic terminologies of spoken English. Hopes anyone could tell me if I am correct about this and give more information on it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a simple example.

Compare:

1. better late **than never**

and

2. better late **than ever**

What do you think the difference is between 1 and 2?

The N in the first sentence a little bit longer than that in the second sentence (i.e. the N is [geminated](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination)). If you don't geminate it, you will end up with '....than ever.'

In *case sensitive*, the first S is geminated, whereas in *k-sensitive*, it's not.

Your assumption is correct for some words, but that's not necessary. For instance, *room-mate*, *fish shop* and *cat tail* are stressed on the first syllable, not the second:

- [ˈɹuːm.meɪt]
- [ˈfɪʃ.ʃɒp]
- [ˈkæt̚teɪl]

Another example would be *unnamed*; if you don't geminate the N, you'll end up with *un-aimed*.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I guess germination is a kind of [linking](https://pronuncian.com/introduction-to-linking). Am I right?

Comment: @swa1nsuen: Yes, you're right. Read the Wikipedia article I linked to in my answer. (It's Gemination, though, not *ge**r**mination*.)

Comment: Nice catch :) I had typed it wrong all the time from hours ago :(

Comment: @swa1nsuen: Happened to me too... I was searching Gemination and my phone auto-corrected it to ge**r**mination