# How to pronounce "Attached to"?

Tags: pronunciation, consonants, consonant-clusters

I pronounce "attached to" like "attach to" when the two words are linked and spoken a little fast ([əˈtæ**tʃ.t**ə]). Is this OK? Or do I have to say [əˈtæt**ʃt.t**ə]?

Comment: Most native speakers pronounce it *attach to* in colloquial speech. You might also hear it being pronounced with a geminated/long [t].

Comment: @Void Could you explain more about the geminated/long [t]? How do you pronounce 't' in a long way?

Comment: I really wonder why some comment posters post really technical stuff that a learner could not possibly understand. It is either rude or overbearing or both.

Comment: @DHK: [Gemination](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/268352/106592) simply means 'lengthening'. Try saying *better late than **never*** and *better late than **ever***; whats the difference? The 'n' of 'than never' is a bit longer than that of 'than ever'. You could say the n is geminated/lengthened.... Gemination of stops/plosives (consonants like p, t, k) is different from that of other consonants in that the first stop/plosive is [unreleased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release)

Comment: @Lambie: What technical stuff are you talking about? If you're referring to 'geminated', then I have written **/long** with it which means that both have more or less the same meaning. I don't think it is rude or overbearing at all. How else could I explain that? Is there a simpler word than LONG?

Comment: Ok, **now** you have explained it but why not post an answer? In any event, I am not convinced that in colloquial speech, the [t] is necessarily unrealized in "attached to". It really depends on the speaker and the circumstances.

Comment: @Lambie I was busy

Comment: Bro, you should have just posted the full answer first. No hate. I'm a native speaker and I had no idea what *gemination* was. Anyhow, I've always heard and said *attached to* as including the *t* sound at the end of *attached*, because that's what differentiates it from *attach*, phonetically. Different words are pronounced differently. This is AmE, SE USA.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you probably know, the *-ed* in 'attached' is pronounced [t] because the sound preceding the *-ed* ('ch') is unvoiced, so 'attached' becomes [əˈtʰæ**t͡ʃt**]<sup>**1**</sup>. However, when 'to' follows 'attached', we get three consonants in a row: [əˈtʰæ**t͡ʃt.tʰ**ə] which can be hard-to-pronounce. The simple way to get round it is to drop the *-ed* ([t]):

- [əˈtʰæ**t͡ʃt.tʰ**ə] → [əˈtʰæ**t͡ʃ.tʰ**ə]

In colloquial speech, most native speakers will simply drop the *-ed* (/t/) and will pronounce it the same as *attach to*. However, you will also hear the *-ed* being pronounced as an unreleased<sup>**2**</sup> 't'. Context will make it clear which form is used, so you shouldn't be worried about it.

---

NOTES:

1. The superscript h [ʰ] represents [aspiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant). Aspiration is the puff of air that accompanies consonants such as p, t, k when they occur at the beginning of a stressed syllable.
2. 'Unreleased' in this context simply means that the consonant (p, t, k usually) has [no release burst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release)

Comment: Re the ch, you said: "because the preceding sound ('ch') is unvoiced" The preceding sound in walk is voiced, and the ed past morpheme, the  ed is pronounced [t] , also.  So.....

Comment: I did not downvote anything. However, I disagree with this: "the -ed in 'attached' is pronounced [t] because the sound preceding the -ed ('ch') is unvoiced," And I am SAYING, that the sound [k] preceding the ed in walk [k], is voiced. So, both cannot be true.

Comment: @Lambie: Is [k] really voiced?!

Comment: No, I guess it is voiceless unlike tag.